# Form Fusion application causes white flash when transitioning between forms. Only in WebLogic, not in Oracle Application Server

Tags: java, forms, oracle, weblogic, fusion

We have an application being hosted on both Oracle Application Server and WebLogic.  When we transition between the forms a quick white flash appears on this application when accessing it through WebLogic.  We can not reproduce this behavior when we access it on Oracle Application Server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue.
The white flash is seeing the background image (the image defined in the formsweb.cfg under the background= parameter.
If you do not define this to an image that is the same color as your canvases you see this image between forms. If you did not set the background parameter it defaults to the white Oracle Forms image so that is what your seeing.

This is a new behavior in 11g.

Mia